# Best practices for Hardhat deployment script?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-deployment

As a newcomer in Solidity, I am trying to understand and create a deploy script that I will use for deploying my contracts.

Stack: Ether.js + hardhat + javascript

Here is the code that I came up with:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const bytecode = 'CONTRACT_BYTECODE';
const abi = [
  // CONTRACT_ABI
];

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://localhost:8545');
const privateKey = 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY';
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const contractConstructorArgs = ["CONSTRUCTOR_ARGUMENTS", 123, true]; // replace with your actual constructor arguments

const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(signer.address);
const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
const estimateGas = await provider.estimateGas({
  from: signer.address,
  data: bytecode
});

const tx = {
  nonce: ethers.utils.hexlify(nonce),
  gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(estimateGas),
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei'),
  data: bytecode + ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(['string', 'uint256', 'bool'], contractConstructorArgs).substr(2),
};

const signedTx = await signer.signTransaction(tx);
const txReceipt = await provider.sendTransaction(signedTx);

const contractAddress = ethers.utils.getAddress(txReceipt.contractAddress);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);

console.log(`Contract deployed at address: ${contractAddress}`);
```

First of all, I would like to know if this code is correct, and second and most important how I can change it to be more effective, have fewer lines of code, and maybe easier to understand.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to write your own deploy script instead of using the one created by the hardhat team?

Comment: meaning? contractFactory?

Comment: The last time I checked the deployment script in their guide worked without issues https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying. I'd try to avoid writing my own deployment scripts if there's an alternative that is supported by the hardhat developers. It could help if the scripts have a motivation and it needs to be checked agains some particular issue. This site isn't the right place for someone to do a security analysis.